# Using one function for two images

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the  following markup

```
<div class="like-buttons">
  <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick()" />
  <span id="clicks">0</span>
  <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick()" />
 </div>
```

And the following JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        if (clicks < 10) {
            clicks += 1;
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is that when `Up` image is clicked the count goes up by 1 to a max of 10 and when `down` is clicked the count to go down by 1 and shouldn't go below 0. Currently the count goes up but I was wondering is there a way which I can add an event for each image in the same function or would I have to write two separate functions one for each image?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: pass in a flag (true for plus and false for down) and then handle the flag in the method.

Comment: This is tagged jQuery but there is no evidence of jQuery being used.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Removed jQuery tag

Comment: What is the lowest possible value ?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan The lowest value is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call onClick() function with param, e.g. onClick(1) (for up button) and onClick(-1) for down button.

```
function onClick(value) {
    var clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML);
    clicks += value;
    if (clicks > 10)
        clicks = 10;
    if (clicks < 0)
        clicks = 0;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

Comment: if you hate if statements ... `clicks = Math.max(0, Math.min(clicks + value, 10));`

Comment: `clicks = Math.max(clicks, 0); clicks = Math.min(clicks, 10);`

Comment: mines better :p - adds the value and limits in one statement

Comment: Thanks for this, It's much appreciated and @JaromandaX I don't mind if statements but you snippet does make my code a lot cleaner so will use it too :)

Comment: Just a small add-on to it. Instead of doing `if(count>=10) count = 10`, you should disable buttons/images. It might create conflict in user experience. User may feel, *I'm clicking on **UP** but count did not increment*.

Have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fmg033c0/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="like-buttons">
  <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick(plus)" />
  <span id="clicks">0</span>
  <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick(min)" />
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML);
    function onClick(type){
        if (type=='plus' && clicks < 10) {
            clicks += 1;
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        } else {
            if (clicks > 0) clicks -= 1;
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : As Johan commented, pass flag. Flag could be true / false or up /down or anything you want which will identify that which button clicked (up or down).

See  below code

```js
var clicks = 0;
function onClick(flag) {
    if(flag && clicks < 10)
      clicks += 1;
    else if(!flag && clicks > 0)
      clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<div class="like-buttons">
  <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true)" />
  <span id="clicks">0</span>
  <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false)" />
</div>
```

Comment: your logic is wrong .. once the clicks gets to 0 or 10 it'll never be able to get off

Comment: 10 will still kill your logic - far easier to use the other answers method ... change, then limit

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar The down click allows the number to go below 0

Comment: read the question again. Nowhere does it say `once at 10, it can't change`

Comment: the question also states 0 being the minimum value

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this snippet if can be a better solution, in order to have multiple images and same result. I've also added a 0 control for -1

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.up').click(function() {
    var clicks = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.clicks').html());
    clicks = clicks +1

    if(clicks == 10) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    
    $(this).parent().find('.clicks').html(clicks);
  });
  
  $('.down').click(function() {
    var clicks = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.clicks').html());
    if(clicks > 0) {
        clicks = clicks - 1
    }

    if(clicks < 10) {
       $(this).parent().find('.up').show()
    }
    
    $(this).parent().find('.clicks').html(clicks);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="up">+1</button>
  <span class="clicks">0</span>
  <button type="button" class="down">-1</button>
</div>

<div class="like-buttons2">
  <button type="button" class="up">+1</button>
  <span class="clicks">0</span>
  <button type="button" class="down">-1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: clicks can go beyond 0 to 10

Comment: I mean, in your answer they can. The question clearly states 0 to 10 as the limit

Comment: still jquery for no reason

Comment: My fault... when I answered there was the JQuery tag, I saw now that the answer was edited...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same function as the event handler for both images. Just check the `id` of the `event` object to check whether to add or subtract.

**Example Snippet**:

```js
var result = 0, 
    img1 = document.getElementById('i1'),
    img2 = document.getElementById('i2'), 
    span = document.getElementById('clicks');

img1.addEventListener('click', calc);
img2.addEventListener('click', calc);

function calc(e) {
    var img = e.target;
    result = img.id == 'i1' ? (result+1) : (result-1);
    result = result < 0 ? 0 : result > 10 ? 10 : result;
    span.textContent = result;
}
```

```css
img { cursor: pointer; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<div class="like-buttons">
    <img id='i1' src="//placehold.it/32x32?text=Up" title="Up" />
    <span id="clicks">0</span>
    <img id='i2' src="//placehold.it/32x32/?text=Dn" title="Down" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clicks = 0;
function onClick(element) {
   var imge = element.src;
   if (clicks < 10 && imge.indexOf('up.png') != -1) {
       clicks++;
   } else if(clicks >0 && imge.indexOf('down.png') != -1) {
       clicks--;
   }
   document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<div class="like-buttons">
  <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick(this)" />
  <span id="clicks">0</span>
  <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick(this)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding logic to @bhushans ans to  complete the requirement when Up image is clicked the count goes up by 1 to a max of 10 and when down is clicked the count to go down by 1 and shouldn't go below 0.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t73v109k/)

```
<div class="like-buttons">
    <img src="up.png" onclick="onClick(true)" /> <span id="clicks">0</span>

    <img src="down.png" onclick="onClick(false)" />
</div>
```

and js  should be

```
var clicks = 0;

function onClick(flag) {

        if (flag) {
            if (clicks < 10) {
            clicks += 1;
        } }else{ 
            if (clicks > 0) {
            clicks -= 1;
        }
        }
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

}
```